# forward video on buffering

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-tv

I am using webapi-avplay to play video on samsung tizen tv web app.
Video starts buffering when I am forwarding the video and after the completion of buffering, video starts playing.
At the time when buffering in progress, I am trying to forward/backward video but unfortunately unable to forward/backward video.
So I want to forward/backward video during buffering. I have searched and read doc but not found any help related to my problem.
So Please help us to getting out from here.

Comment: actually I think it's impossible to do anything while the video is buffering

Comment: @El 9ar9ni thanks for reply. have you any idea how youtube application or any other samsung tizen tv application implement this functionality ??

Comment: try using the onbufferingprogress event like mentioned in the answer above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried coding inside **onbufferingprogress** method. Like:

```
var listener = {

    onbufferingprogress: function(percent) {
        console.log("Buffering in progress");
        loadingObj.setPercent(percent);

        /* Move 5 seconds back */ 
        var back_button = document.getElementById("v-back"); /* Back button */
        back_button.addEventListener("click", function() {              
          video.currentTime -= 5        
         }, false);
    }
}

webapis.avplay.setListener(listener);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this get called in the middle of a video too? even when buffering has completed fully?  I submitted a buffering indicator fix to them and they're still showing it freezing in the middle of playback and resuming but no progress indicator is being shown.  Trying to figure out if this event is what I need to be using to get any buffering mid-video.

Answer (score 1):

when you are trying to seek you should pause the video after that you should seek visually update the progress bar and current time. When the user stopped seeking you should use webapis.avplay.seekTo(seekingTime) and play the video. It works for me.

```
const handleSeekForward = () => {
setForwardSteps((prev) => prev + 1);
player().pause();

const seekTime = player().getCurrentTime() + 2 * clamp(forwardSteps(), 3, 120);

if (seekTime > player()?.getDuration()) {
  return;
}

const progress = progressUpdate(player()?.getCurrentTime());
setCurrentProgress(progress);

if (hasNativeHLS()) {
  const hour = getHours(seekTime);
  const minutes = getMinutes(seekTime);
  const seconds = getSeconds(seekTime);

  setCurrentTime(`${hour}:${minutes}:${seconds}`);
}

player().seek(seekTime);
```

};